# pyhton TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, calculator

`If I enter input with parentheses it resolves only what is inside the parentheses and not what is after or before, if I enter two expressions with parentheses it returns None. you can see it in the code.

```
def divide(a, b):
    return a/b
def pow(a, b):
    return a**b
def addA(a, b):
    return a+b
def subA(a, b):
    return a-b
def mul (a, b):
    return a*b

operators = {
  '+': addA,
  '-': subA,
  '*': mul,
  '/': divide,
  '^': pow,


}
def extract_expression(s):
    start = s.index('[')
    end = s.rindex(']')
    while ']' in s:

        return s[start + 1:end]

def calculate(s):
    while '[' in s:
        sub_expression = extract_expression(s)
        result = calculate(sub_expression)
        s = s.replace('[' + sub_expression + ']', str(result))

    if s.isdigit():
        return float(s)

    for c in operators.keys():
        left, operator, right = s.partition(c)
        if operator in operators:
            return operators[operator](calculate(left), calculate(right))

calc = input("Type calculation:\n")
print("Answer: " + str(calculate(calc)))
```

Comment: Please show us the exact input you used to get that error.  Don't make us guess.

Comment: my bad sorry the input was 2+[1+2]

Comment: Pretty sure the issue is that `calculate(s)` doesn't always hit one of its two `return` statements, and when it doesn't hit a `return`, the default in python is to return `None`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre]. We don't provide a debugging service.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is during the second step when he calculates 2+3.0 -> `s.isdigit()` when s is 3.0 returns false.
This is why 3.0 is never returned. Then he tries to calculate addA(2,None) which results in your error.

What you can try is to replace `s.isdigit()` with your own written check which includes floats.

The function to replace `s.isdigit()` can look like this:

```
def is_float_digit(n: str) -> bool:
    try:
        float(n)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

The entire code could look like this:

```
def divide(a, b):
    return a/b
def pow(a, b):
    return a**b
def addA(a, b):
    return a+b
def subA(a, b):
    return a-b
def mul (a, b):
    return a*b

operators = {
  '+': addA,
  '-': subA,
  '*': mul,
  '/': divide,
  '^': pow,
}


def is_float_digit(n: str) -> bool:
    try:
        float(n)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def extract_expression(s):
    start = s.index('[')
    end = s.rindex(']')
    while ']' in s:

        return s[start + 1:end]

def calculate(s):
    while '[' in s:
        sub_expression = extract_expression(s)
        result = calculate(sub_expression)
        s = s.replace('[' + sub_expression + ']', str(result))

    if is_float_digit(s):
        return float(s)

    for c in operators.keys():
        left, operator, right = s.partition(c)
        if operator in operators:
            return operators[operator](calculate(left), calculate(right))

calc = input("Type calculation:\n")
print("Answer: " + str(calculate(calc)))
```